# Using data from firebaseDB with cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to pre-render metas with google cloud functions but I can't figure out how to acces the values, the data log returns this on the functions console (see link)

[image: console.log(data) returns this]

```
    exports.preLoadMeta = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    let id = request.url.split("/");
    let data;

    admin.database().ref('proyectos').orderByChild("urlAmigable").equalTo(id[2]).once("value")
        .then(proyectos =>{
            data = proyectos.val();
            console.log(data)
        }).then( () => {
            response.status(200).send(`
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>${data.titulo}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="bla bla - ${data.titulo}" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="${data.titulo}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="${data.meta}" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="${data.imgUrl}" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
            `);
        })
})
```

(this does not work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're expecting your query to return the child instead of the collection. You need to get the child (even though there's only one in this case). Try using this code for your snapshot instead:

```
proyectos.forEach(child => {
  data = child.val()
});
```